# wsf php use 2048 bits encryption

Tags: php, wso2, wsh

I use wsf php as a soap client.

I have a 2048 bits certificate which makes wsf php break.

When I use a 1024 bits on the test environment, everything works fine.

Can anyone help? (btw: the log(lvl4) just stops )

gr

Answer (score 1):

Your problem must be related to the bug report [WSFPHP-457](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/WSFPHP-457).

You can find workaround information but you have to recompile library.